# Roboto font package makes text un-copyable in LaTeX output

Tags: fonts, pdf, texlive, texlive-2019, texlive-2020

The Roboto package seems to mess with the text content, so when you copy your resulting text, it adds or removes some spaces, depending on the PDF viewer.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing
% font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Go here}

\lipsum

\section{New}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Now copy the text from the resulting PDF.

Copied from Evince it adds spaces to each word:

```
r s it a m e t , c o n s e c t e t u e r a d ip is c in g
p la c e ra t a c , a d ip is c in g
n o n u m m y
v it a e , f e lis .
C u ra b it u r d ic t u m
e g e t , c o n s e c t e t u e r id , v u lp u t a t e
P e lle n t e s q u e
```

Copied from Firefox it removes all spaces and adds wired characters – or it does the same.

It is **not alwaays reproducible** and all I could find out is that the **Roboto** package causes it. If this is removed, it always works.
However, it *may* also work if you don't do this.
I could not find a package or whatever that causes this.

This is TexLive 2019.
Compiled with LuaLaTex.

### 2020

However, when I used Overleave for testing it with TexLive 2020, it also seems to work. Was there a bug fix?

However, it now still **removes the line endings**:

```latex
1 IntroductionLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpisegestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urnafringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est,iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabiturauctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsaneleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.1.1 Go hereLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero,nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpisegestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urnafringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est,iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabiturauctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsaneleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor loremnon justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec ali-quet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metusa mi.  Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.  Suspendisse ut massa.  Cras nec ante.Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunttristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante.Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis,molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifendat, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi
```

Online test: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rjxbpskncnqk

**Edit:** Okay, forget that last part. That may be a bug of Firefox/[pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) (in Overleaf) and also happens with other PDFs. Because if I now view it with Evince, it works.

Tested with LuaLaTex and pdfLaTeX.

### Questions

- What is the cause of this issue? In which situations does it break?
- Is there a bug report for the Roboto package? I could not even find a bug tracker.
- Is there a workaround that works in TexLive 2019?
- Is it really fixed in TexLive 2020, as I guessed?

Comment: well if it works in a current system a bug report doesn't make much sense. But beside this: copy&paste depends also on the pdf viewer you use. I had once a bug in sumatra which inserted spaces everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but it's certainly not (only) a bug in the PDF viewer, because I've tried it with different ones.